# variable template syntax for global constants definition

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, one-definition-rule, variable-templates

*C++14*-way to define global constant `x` of some type `X` is:

```
struct X { int i; char c; };
template< typename = void >
X const x_impl{1, 'x'};
static X const & x = x_impl<>;
```

[The technique](https://ericniebler.github.io/std/wg21/D4381.html) allows us to avoid ODR-violation (due to external linkage of variable templates).

But for function templates there is a handy possibility to omit angle brackets in following cases:

```
template< typename T >
void f(T) {}

template< typename T = void >
void g() {}

// ...
f< int >(1);
f<>(1);
f(2); // also valid
g<>();
g(); // also valid
```

Are there any theoretical reasons to deny the possibility to refer to a variable template without template argument list, even if all the (non-type) template parameters have default (values)? It'll be very convenient to be able to define a global constants (say, in header-only library) in a form like following:

```
template< int = 0 >
A const a{1, 'a'};
```

and then to be able to refer to `a` without any angle brackets.

```
std::cout << &a << std::endl; // odr-using
```

Comment: Well, in your example, which `a` are you referring to ? `a<int>` ? `a<void>` ?

Comment: @Synxis Of course, similar to the nullary function case (as already illustrated in the question) `a` should refer to `a< ... >` where `...` is defaults (or default values for non-type parameters).

Comment: Well, that makes sense. I guess the best place to have some answer about the rationale is to go on isocpp forums - there a numerous C++ commitee members there

Comment: There is a list of forums here: https://isocpp.org/forums. I guess you can post in future proposals...

Comment: Well, there would be ambiguities with `<`, and with variables `<` is a fairly common operation, unlike functions.